# Hadoop Node failure?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, nodes

I have queries on Hadoop Node. We have 3 clusters with each cluster having 5 nodes.

1. How to know if a particular node is down/inaccessable. ?
2. How to know that the data on a node is actually processed by Map Reduce program ?
3. How to know if a particular cluster is down/inaccessable. ?
4. How to see output of Map Reduce of only a certain node. ?

Comment: all the answers are in the web UI of the master nodes.